# How to check if "localize=english" else if "localize=other language" ... in code behind - (ASP.NET C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I have a localized website and I'm using LINQ to call some procedures - those procedures contain some texts that I need to be translated after language switch. This is one of my procedure calls:

```
public static IQueryable VyhledejCPN()
        {
            LINQDataContext db = new LINQDataContext();
            IQueryable result = db.spSearchPartNumber(PartNumber).AsQueryable();
            return result;
        }
```

And I need something like this:

```
if (localize == english)
            {
                public static IQueryable VyhledejCPN()
                    {
                        LINQDataContext db = new LINQDataContext();
                        IQueryable resultEN = db.spSearchPartNumberEN(PartNumber).AsQueryable();
                        return resultEN;
                    }
            }

            else if (localize == czech)
            {
                public static IQueryable VyhledejCPN()
                    {
                        LINQDataContext db = new LINQDataContext();
                        IQueryable resultCZ = db.spSearchPartNumberCZ(PartNumber).AsQueryable();
                        return resultCZ;
                    }
            }
```

Or is there some other way?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the culture of the client, you could use the [`HttpRequest.UserLanguages` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userlanguages.aspx) (the `Accept-Language header` of the browser for the language priority).

> Gets a sorted string array of client language preferences.
>
> The language names are provided by the browser, and there is no
>   definitive list of all possible codes. Typically these consist of a
>   two-character codes for the language, a hyphen, and a two-character
>   code for the culture, such as "en-us" for U.S. English and "fr-ca" for
>   Canadian French.

```
int count;
String[] userLang = Request.UserLanguages;    

for (count = 0; count < userLang.Length; count++) 
{
   Response.Write("User Language " + count +": " + userLang[count] + "<br>");
}
```

So in your case:

```
if (Request.UserLanguages.Contains("en-US"))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works! Could you advice me how to make this works also in relation to language change - because I'm letting users change their langueage manualy just to be shure, like this:

`protected void btnLangChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton languageButton = sender as LinkButton;

        Session["Culture"] = languageButton.CommandArgument;

        // Reload last requested page with new culture.
        Response.Redirect(Request.Path);
    }`

Comment: Then you have to check first if the `Session` variable is set and what language it contains before you use my code above. `if(Session["Culture"] != null){//check this lang}else{//my code above}`.